# Add the date on the top of each group of chats like in what's app

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat, firebase

I'm trying to add date on top of the messages sent and receive on a particular day in my chat app. For instance:

```
-----Yesterday-----

mike: Hello

Jan: Hi

-----Today----

Eunice: Help! I've been trying to do this all day

Fid: Me too. Lets ask for help.
```

I have written the JS to calculate the date and tried to append to the top of the messages sent daily. 
Here is what I've done:

- add the day of the week as a classname to messages sent on the day
- use jQuery to select the first element with the classname (day of the week). 
   Firbase is the bomb
   Yes for sure
   I'm still learning it though
- append html tag e.g `Today` to the first div

Here is my JS

```
last10Comments.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
var comment = snapshot.val();
var newDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("comment ").attr("id",snapshot.name()).appendTo("#comments");
  FB.api("/" + comment.userid, function(userdata) {
    comment.name = userdata.name;
    newDiv.html(Mustache.to_html($('#template').html(), comment));
  });
var outputTime = $("<span/>").addClass("timespan "+ te.getDayName() +"").attr("id",yiu).appendTo("#comments").text(Timeformat());

var tim = $('.'+ te.getDayName() +'')[0];
$('#'+tim+'').prepend( "<p>Test</p>" );
})
```

This JS actually gets the first element. but the probelem is, it prepend the text based on the number of element with the same class. i.e if 5 divs contain same classname, it prepends it 5 times. e.g `Wednesday Wednesday Wednesday Wednesday Wednesday`

Comment: What is the variable `te`?

Answer (score 2):

I have no way to try out, so I am just guessing here, try this:

```
last10Comments.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  (function (te) {
    var comment = snapshot.val();
    var newDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("comment ").attr("id", snapshot.name()).appendTo("#comments");
    FB.api("/" + comment.userid, function (userdata) {
      comment.name = userdata.name;
      newDiv.html(Mustache.to_html($('#template').html(), comment));
    });
    var outputTime = $("<span/>").addClass("timespan " + te.getDayName() + "").attr("id", yiu).appendTo("#comments").text(Timeformat());

    var tim = $('.' + te.getDayName() + '')[0];
    $('#' + tim + '').prepend("<p>Test</p>");
  })(te);
})
```

Let me know it if works. If it fixes your problem, then I will explain in comments.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Will let you know in 5mins

Comment: do you have a loop for the days? If yes, you need to give a bit more code from the loop scope onwards.

Comment: No it doesn't. first the error in the console say "te" is not defined. When I remove "te" the initial problem persists.

Comment: here's the function for days                              (function() {
    var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

    Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
        return months[ this.getMonth() ];
    };
    Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
        return days[ this.getDay() ];
    };
})();

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) representing the issue?

Comment: This seems different from your original issue? I don't see `Wednesday`s mentioned anywhere?

Comment: its the same issue. Replace "te.getDayName()" around line 62 with "te.getDayName()".     http://jsfiddle.net/cevic/uZ5u5/6/

Comment: > Replace "te.getDayName()" around line 62 with "te.getDayName()" ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I meant if you replace the function, it will print dates. but you could see the repetition though.

Comment: Hi bits I thought you wanted to help? Please try if you can I'm stuck. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I got busy. Today I tried to get back at it, but it seems comments are not coming anymore in your fiddle.

Comment: I resolved the issue with fiddle please use this link instead: http://jsfiddle.net/cevic/yt3tC/7/. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have made some changes to simplify the complexity you had created unknowingly. Also, I wanted to make sure that you are grouping based on actual dates, rather than merely names of days. Otherwise if people have not communicated in a week will find all their sundays collapsed. Does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yt3tC/12/) look right?